# Action that fires after store has been changed

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I have following Store and Actions

```
const AliceStore = Reflux.createStore({
  update() {
    var aliceNewValue = ...
    this.trigger(aliceNewValue);
  }
});

const BobActions = Reflux.createActions(['notifyBob']);
```

and now I want to fire `BobActions.notifyBob(aliceNewValue)` after every call of `AliceStore.trigger(aliceNewValue)`.
I know I can fire it from `AliceStore` after `this.trigger(aliceNewValue)` but I want to somehow setup listening in `BobActions` like this: `AliceStore.listen(this.onAliceStoreChange)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another store to listen for `AliceStore` change, I think that what you are looking for is here: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#listening-to-changes-in-other-data-stores-aggregate-data-stores

If you need to do this from a component, then you should just listen to the `AliceStore` change event in the component and then trigger the `notifyBob`

If you want to do all the logic inside `AliceStore` then you can make your custom trigger function that does the trigger then dispatches the action so you don't repeat yourself.